# pl/sql: convert cursor type to row object

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a pipeline function as

```
row_t AS OBJECT(...);
table_t IS TABLE OF row_t
func_a RETURN table_t PIPELINED AS ...
```

And another function which will take `row_t` as parameter:

```
func_b(row_in row_t)
```

Now, in a procedure, I would like to pass each row from pipeline function to `func_b`

```
FOR c IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(func_a()))
LOOP
    -- The following code gives compilation error,
    -- How do I convert c to row_t type???
    some_var := func_b(c);
    ...
END LOOP;
```

Any suggestion? Thanks all in advance!

Comment: Another question: what is the type of c in the FOR loop above anyway??

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace type row_t as object(a number, b number);

create or replace type table_t is table of row_t;

create or replace function func_a return table_t pipelined as
    v_row_t row_t := row_t(1, 2);
begin
    pipe row (v_row_t);
end;
/

create or replace function func_b(row_in row_t) return number as
begin
    return 3;
end;
/

declare
    v_row_t row_t;
    v_result number;
begin
    for c in
    (
        select * from table(func_a())
    ) loop
        v_result := func_b(row_t(c.a, c.b));
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem is row_t has many columns, and I would really like to avoid explicitly create row_t in this fashion... Is it possible to modify func_a signature so that it can take a cursor type parameter? Thanks again!

Comment: How are you using this pipelined function?  If it's only returning a small amount of data, it might be easier to `v_row_t row_t := func_a;` and then loop through the collection.  If you're processing a large amount of data, then you may want to chain them in SQL like this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#BCGCBDGC.  I don't think there's a more concise syntax for your specific question.